# What could cause ViewData["x"].ToString to not work?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display a colorpicker on an MVC5 application. This feature works if manually typed out and adapted for each page that uses it. Obviously, this is excessively duplicated code so I created a Utils method to generate the data. Here is the definition for that method:

```
    public static string GetColorsList()
    {
        string colorsList = "<option style=\"color:gray\" value=\"null\">select color</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:azure\" value=\"Azure\">Azure</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:blue\" value=\"Blue\">Blue</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:cyan\" value=\"Cyan\">Cyan</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:green\" value=\"Green\">Green</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:magenta\" value=\"Magenta\">Magenta</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:orange\" value=\"Orange\">Orange</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:red\" value=\"Red\">Red</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:violet\" value=\"Violet\">Violet</option>" +
                            "<option style=\"color:yellow\" value=\"Yellow\">Yellow</option>";

        return colorsList;
    }
```

The reason I return a string instead of an IEnumerable is that a JS method adds new data (i.e. create a new row in the table) to the page using:

```
$(#tablename tbody).append(newcontent);
```

where new content is a string of the HTML to insert. Ideally I could just create an Html.DropDownList to display the picker contents but this does not return a string-friendly result.

**What I want to accomplish**: take colorsList, put in in ViewData["x"], turn ViewData["x"] into a string, and concat that string with other content that belongs in newcontent.

ViewData["x"].ToString() yields the following result:

```
&lt;option style=&quot;color:gray&quot; value=&quot;null&quot;&gt;select 
color&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option style=&quot;color:azure&quot; value=&quot;
Azure&quot;&gt;Azure&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option style=
&quot;color:blue&quot; 
value=&quot;Blue&quot;&gt;Blue&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option style=&quot;
color:cyan&quot; value=&quot;Cyan&quot;&gt;Cyan&lt;/option&gt;&lt;
option style=&quot;color:green&quot; value=&quot;Green&quot;&gt;
Green&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option style=&quot;color:magenta&quot; value=
&quot;Magenta&quot;&gt;Magenta&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option style=
&quot;color:orange&quot; value=&quot;Orange&quot;&gt;Orange&lt;/option
&gt;&lt;option style=&quot;color:red&quot; value=&quot;Red&quot;&gt;
Red&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option style=&quot;color:violet&quot; value=
&quot;Violet&quot;&gt;Violet&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option style=
&quot;color:yellow&quot; value=&quot;Yellow&quot;&gt;Yellow&lt;/option&gt;);
```

The workaround here is to run:

```
        colorpickerContent = colorpickerContent.replace("$lt;", "<");
        colorpickerContent = colorpickerContent.replace("$gt;", ">");
        colorpickerContent = colorpickerContent.replace("&quot;", "\"");
```

So that all the proper characters exist. When running, the program throws a syntax error because the output does not start with the quotation marks needed to consider it a string. Any suggestions on how I can make ViewData["x"] a workable string? I attempted JSON.stringify() but found similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [HtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx) that one won't be escaped.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed what I needed!